# PuTTy Connection timed out for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I created Ubuntu instance in EC2. And worked fine so far.

But somehow I can't connect to the server by PuTTy anymore and I get `Network error: Connection timed out`.

1. The instance is running in the console.
2. CPU uses just 2%.
3. InBound Setting seems no problem. SSH with 22 port.
4. Tried with the IP address and DNS.
5. restarted the instance and Tried.
6. Stopped and tried with different IP address.
7. Instance connection is fine.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

This is inbound rule:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A **Connection timeout** is a sign that your computer is unable reach the remote computer. Such an error normally takes some time before it fails.

If, instead, the remote computer rejected the connection, the error would appear immediately and the message would be `Permission denied`.

Things to check:

- The **Security Group** on the EC2 instance needs to allow inbound SSH (port 22) access either from the whole internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) or, preferably, from a smaller CIDR range that includes your computer (eg choosing "My IP" in the console). This is typically the cause of the issue 80% of the time.
- The instance needs to be in a **Public Subnet**, which means the subnet is connected to an Internet Gateway.
- Your **network must allow an outbound SSH connection** to AWS. Some corporate networks might block this.
- There are some other potential causes, but most of the time the cause is one of the above.

Comment: I've checked all, but can't still solve the problem. Is it possible if this can be caused by  terminal commands?

Comment: Have you every managed to connect to another EC2 instance? If so, was it in the same subnet? If you launch a new instance (eg Amazon Linux) in the same subnet, can you connect? Can you try from another network (eg home, office, tethered via phone) to determine whether it is caused by the _outbound_ network? It definitely has to do with network/reachability, not the instance itself.

Comment: Yes, I tried in several different places and got the same result. I had one instance. So, I created new instance and tried. And the new instance is working fine. I need to recover the first instance and I have no idea...

Comment: Are both instances in the same Subnet, with the same Security Group?